# loading url in an iframe and adding a class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

i have a situation very similar to this: http://bradfrost.com/demo/ish/

what i need to do is the following: when I input a new url in the bar and press GO, the `iframe` should be given a class.

i have tried

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $("iframe").addClass("new-class")
});
```

but the whole page gets reloaded and i lose the newly added class. is there any other way to do this?

my page is in `php` and the html is the following

```
<?php $src = (empty($_GET['url'])) ? 'http://css-tricks.com/' : addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));?>
    <header class="header">
        <form method="get" action="" id="url-form">
            <label for="url" id="url-toggle" class="url-toggle">URL</label>
             <input id="url" type="text" name="url" placeholder="Enter any URL" value="<?php echo $src; ?>" />
             <button id="url-submit">Go</button>
          </form>
    </header>

    <iframe id="sg-viewport" src="<?php echo $src; ?>" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms"></iframe>

    <footer class="footer">
        footer
    </footer>
```

thanks for helping :)

Comment: ok, then tell me what you're trying to achieve, what should happen?

Comment: @Romko i enter the page. i insert an url i choose, i click the button and the resulting refreshed iframe gets a class added

Answer (score 0):

you should intercept form submission. try this:

```
$("#url-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("iframe").addClass("new-class");
});
```

Comment: this works but it just adds the class , preventing to actually load the url

Answer (score 0):

The iframe is resetting.  However, you might get what you need by targeting the contents of the iframe.

$("iframe").contents().find("#chosenElement").addClass("myClass");

Comment: tried this 

```jQuery(window).load(function () {
$("iframe").contents().find("body").addClass("myClass");
});```

but it's not working :/